# what does "%-9s" does?

Tags: c, format-specifiers

I am working on a C project and right now using an open source method to be integrated to my code. While going through the code, I got across a **printf** statement that is like this :

```
printf("%-9s",someString);
```

I understand the format-specifier **%s** but what is **%9s** ?

I tried looking for solutions for this but no success. Any help would be useful.

Comment: Did you try? to observe the behavior.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Experimenting tells you what happens in certain cases. It does not prove the rule. The appropriate way to determine what something means is to read applicable documentation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I believe learn by practicals with some code is very helpful and easy. But Yes I agree language standard/documentation can tell about exact behavior.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
printf("%-9s",someString);
```

9 is field width. If you pass string as `Hi`, this will print `Hi` and seven spaces.

If you pass string as `Hai`, this will print `Hai` and six spaces.

`-` says left align.

**Edit**

These lines of Code explains Little more.

```
 printf("\n%-9s%s", "Hello", "World!");  // left align,   Here "Hello" is five characters, because of width -9, prints 4 more spaces after Hello  

 printf("\n%9s%s", "Hello", "World!");   // right align,  because of width 9, prints 4 more spaces before Hello  
 printf("\n%+9s%s", "Hello", "World!");  // right align,  because of width 9, prints 4 more spaces before Hello.
```

All above cases field width used for `"Hello"` string only not for `"World!"` string this prints normally.

**Output**

```
Hello    World!
    HelloWorld!
    HelloWorld!
```

Comment: Hi Gangadhar, I followed your steps and got the result but when I used **printf("%-9s %s","My","Hello");**, it gave output **7spaces+My Hello **. It put spaces to the left of the string. is it right?

Comment: @CodingPassionate: I tested `printf("%-9s %s","My","Hello");` with Apple clang 5.0, and it printed “My[seven spaces]Hello”. If your C implementation produced “[seven spaces]My Hello”, then it is broken. Are you sure that code produced that output?

Comment: @Gangadhar: Sorry, it was **printf("%9s %s","My","Hello");** and this outputted **7spaces+My Hello **. is this the coreect way?

Comment: @CodingPassionate no problem.Yes that is correct. see http://ideone.com/yX7BXC  you can understand more better

Comment: You would like to add [this code type of code](http://codepad.org/J6rIBoK2) may be help further users. I think it show difference between `%9s` and `%-9s`. (is although OP got his answer)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan good thing. I will add. same i was posted in  above comment.

Answer (score 0):

`-` sign in the format specifier used to left justify the output within the specified field.
In `%-9s`, `9` is the field width and `-` before it tells the compiler to left justify the output.

Answer (score 0):

`%9s` this means if your string to display has a length less than 9 then display the string and padding it with white space till the length reach 9 charachters

Comment: This does not explain the `-`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I answered to his question: `I understand the format-specifier %s but what is %9s ?`

Comment: The answer receiving votes up answered the question in the title and explained the entire specifier. It is clearly a superior answer to one that omits explanation of the `-`.